# Scatter matrix for Iris data

Tags: python, scatter-plot, scatter-matrix

colleagues new to Python but got a challenge to do scatter matrix for the Iris data *without using a la*b.

I thought a for loop can be used to plot scatter by literately one feature on another.

I have put all the features as X. Please advise what kind of mess ,i have done in the code below- i am getting "x and Y must be of equal size error". How else would you do it?

```
for c in X:
    plt.scatter(c,X[:,0:4] )
    plt.show
```

*THANKS*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after multiple trials, this is one of the answers i managed to develop scatter matrix with histograms in the diagonal . Edits to improve the code are welcome, particularly how do i add legend to the scatter plots? thanks

```
fig = plt.figure( figsize=(8.5,8.5))
t= 1
for i in range (0,4):
    for j in range (0,4):
        if i==j:
            fig.add_subplot(4,4,t)
            plt.hist(X[:,i])
            plt.xlabel( feature_names[i] )
       
        else:
                    fig.add_subplot(4,4,t)
                    plt.scatter(X[:, i], X[:, j],cmap=plt.cm.Paired,c=Y, s=6)
                    plt.xlabel( feature_names[i] )
                    plt.ylabel( feature_names[j] )
                 #legend(feature_names[Y])
        t=t+1
```